# Current method for deploying react app to Google App Engine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, mern

I have a MERN stack project I'm developing (first time with this stack). I'm trying to figure out how to deploy this project live via Google App Engine. Other projects I've worked on, I just configure an app.yaml file and then use node.js to serve html/css/javascript to the front end.

In this app, I have a "frontend" folder and a "backend folder" and I'm wondering now how I merge these two into a single folder that I deploy via GAE. Suggestions I saw all recommending bringing the project in from Github, but I'm not using that currently on this project, and would like to just deploy from the terminal in VSCode like I have in my previous projects.

It seems like I can either deploy the backend or the frontend, but not both, which is obviously a problem. Is there a simpler service to use that would be better suited for this app?

EDIT: more info. I currently have a frontend folder which runs my react frontend set up on localhost:3000, and it proxies requests to my node.js backend (set up in a backend folder) on localhost:8080 - if that setup helps anyone answer the question.

Thanks in advance, I'm not sure where to begin since this stack is new to me.

Comment: Don't know if this is the most efficient way but what about keeping them separate and deploying them as separate services to the same project (a front end service and a backend service). Take a look at [multi-service Architecture](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configuration-files#examples) in GAE

Comment: Have you tried solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70688976/18265570)?